# How do I intercept the event when the user clicks the "close" button in a toplevel window?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, tkx

When the user clicks the system-provided close button in a toplevel window, I need to free resources.

The question:  how do I intercept this event, so that I can call some of my own code?

I've looked through [the docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/toplevel.htm), but can't find anything about destroying toplevel windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tkx;

my $mw = Tkx::widget->new('.');
$mw->g_wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW' => \&cleanUp);

Tkx::MainLoop();

sub cleanUp
{
   print "Cleaning things up\n";
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Works great so far!  I went ahead and removed `use warnings;` because it was in there twice.

Comment: @Matt: But perhaps you _really_ want the warnings to be there? :-)